# why explicitly implementing an event?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reading *CLR via C# by Jeffrey Richter* which says:

```
public event EventHandler<NewMailEventArgs> NewMail;
```

When the C# compiler compiles the line above, it translates this single line of source code into the
following three constructs:

```
private EventHandler<NewMailEventArgs> NewMail = null;

// 2. A PUBLIC add_Xxx method (where Xxx is the Event name)
public void add_NewMail(EventHandler<NewMailEventArgs> value) {
  ... // use Delegate.Combine internally
}

// 3. A PUBLIC remove_Xxx method (where Xxx is the Event name) allows methods to unregister interest in the event.
public void remove_NewMail(EventHandler<NewMailEventArgs> value) {
  ... // use Delegate.Remove internally
}
```

and the author says:

> The System.Windows.Forms.Control type defines about 70 events. If the Control type implemented the events by allowing the compiler to implicitly generate the add and remove accessor methods and delegate fields, every Control object would have 70 delegate fields in it just for the events! Because most programmers care about just a few events, an enormous amount of memory would be wasted for each object created from a Control-derived type. To efficiently store event delegates, each object that exposes events will maintain a collection (usually a dictionary) with some sort of event identifier as the key and a delegate list as the value.

So for example, we should explicitly implementing an event in a type as:

```
public sealed class EventKey { }

public sealed class EventSet {
   private readonly Dictionary<EventKey, Delegate> m_events = new Dictionary<EventKey, Delegate>();

   // Adds an EventKey -> Delegate mapping if it doesn't exist or combines a delegate to an existing EventKey
   public void Add(EventKey eventKey, Delegate handler) {
     ...
   }

   // Removes a delegate from an EventKey (if it exists) and
   // removes the EventKey -> Delegate mapping if the last delegate is removed
   public void Remove(EventKey eventKey, Delegate handler) {
     ...
   }

   // Raises the event for the indicated EventKey
   public void Raise(EventKey eventKey, Object sender, EventArgs e) {
      ... // use Delegate.DynamicInvoke internally
   }
}

public class TypeWithLotsOfEvents {
   private readonly EventSet m_eventSet = new EventSet();

   protected static readonly EventKey s_fooEventKey = new EventKey();

   public event EventHandler<FooEventArgs> Foo {
      add { m_eventSet.Add(s_fooEventKey, value); }
      remove { m_eventSet.Remove(s_fooEventKey, value); }
   }
   ...
}
```

I don't why this approach is more efficient, it still need to declare each event it contains, and for derived types of TypeWithLotsOfEvents, the child instances will contain all the parent's delegate fields, so nothing you can save? Taking the windows form control type which contains 70 events, any derived control type will have to contain 70 events as well because the inheritance hierarchy

Comment: `I don't why this approach is more efficient` Presumably because there aren't 70 fields, just like it says.

Comment: Which book? This sounds like premature optimization.

Comment: @mjwills Instead of this question saying a book, it should say CLR via C# by Jeffrey Richter.

Comment: I interpreted the quoted passage as saying the `Control` class provides that collection for you.  I don't think it is suggesting you implement such a collection yourself.

Comment: `the child instances will contain all the parent's delegate fields, so nothing you can save?` How did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: I seem to recall you've made this kind of misunderstanding before: methods, properties and events do not use up memory per object just by existing, they only use memory once per class. Only fields add memory usage per object, therefore storing only registered events in a dictionary is much more efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to note here is that this...

```
public event EventHandler<FooEventArgs> Foo {
  add { m_eventSet.Add(s_fooEventKey, value); }
  remove { m_eventSet.Remove(s_fooEventKey, value); }
}
```

does not generate any fields.

This generates *only* two methods:

```
private void add_Foo(EventHandler<FooEventArgs> value) {
    m_eventSet.Add(s_fooEventKey, value); 
}

private void remove_Foo(EventHandler<FooEventArgs> value) {
    m_eventSet.Remove(s_fooEventKey, value);
}
```

This is rather similar to how auto-implemented properties generate a backing-field plus a getter and setter method, whereas non-auto-implemented properties generate only the getter and setter methods.

Note that you would still have the field `s_fooEventKey`, but that one is static, so there is only one instance of it ever, rather than one instance of the field per instance of `TypeWithLotsOfEvents`. So we are all fine.

Try using reflection to print out the private fields of `Control`. You will see that it doesn't fields that correspond to its events. On the other hand, if you write your own class without using the "dictionary of events" approach, and try to print out its fields, you will see there is a field for each event you declare.